# All data in the db is lost when closing a express based node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I am running a node.js server locally using express and while the server is running I can POST data to the server's db fine and I am able to get the data making a get request on the same cycle. However, if I close the server and reopen it, all the data is lost and essentially the db is empty if I make another GET request.

This is for an express node.js sever currently running on windows.

// app.js

```
app.post('/api/v1/todos', (req, res) => {


 const todo = {
   id: db.length + 1,
   title: req.body.title,
   user: req.body.user,
    data: req.body.data 
 }
 db.push(todo);
 return res.status(201).send({
   success: 'true',
   message: 'todo added successfully',
   todo
 })
});
```

// Request from web app

```
    $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/todos",
         data: {
          title: title,
          user: "user",
      data: output },
         type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data, status) {
                    console.log(status);

                },
                contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            });
}
```

Comment: where is your database? please provide as much detail as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Firstly welcome to Web Development & Stack Overflow

The express server that is created when you start it is a dynamic entity. It persists as long as that entity is running.

#### Everytime you start a server a fresh entity is created. And everytime you close a server that particular entity is destroyed completely.

## Solution

### Databases like MySQL, MongoDB:

What you will do while using these databases is that you will use their APIs to store data from server to them. And they don't get destroyed when server is closed as they reside in your **Hard Drive**.

---

**Start working with databases, they are best partners in web development.**

#### GOOD LUCK!